# OSGi dependency hell: ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.WrappedValue

Tags: enums, jaxb, osgi, moxy, equinox

I had working environment with Equinox, Jersey and MOXy. Jersey uses MOXy to parse JSON and bind to bean objects. After changing one field type of some @XmlRootElement class to enum, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jaxb/WrappedValue
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.JaxbClassLoader.generateClass(JaxbClassLoader.java:124)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateWrapperClass(MappingsGenerator.java:3232)
...
```

MOXy bundle seems to be fine:

```
osgi> lb -l
...
50|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar
...
```

There is the class in the jar

```
$ jar tf plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar | grep Wrapped
org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jaxb/WrappedValue.class
```

and package is exported

```
osgi> bundle 50
...
Exported packages
  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb; version="2.6.0"[exported]
...
```

so why do I get ClassNotFoundException?

EDIT:
bundes:

```
0|Active     |    0|System Bundle
1|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.mongodb.morphia_0.110.0.jar
2|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javax.validation.api_1.1.0.Final.jar
3|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/classmate_1.0.0.jar
4|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.hibernate.validator_5.1.3.Final.jar
5|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/commons-logging_1.1.1.jar
6|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
7|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/com.thoughtworks.proxytoys_1.0.0.jar
8|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
9|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.200.v20131021-1843.jar
10|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:../../../../edu.zut.aci.nsg.restapi/
11|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.mongodb.morphia.util_0.110.0.jar
12|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20140312-2051.jar
13|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.500.v20140318-1755.jar
14|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.javax.json_1.0.4.jar
15|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.ext.jersey-bean-validation_2.17.0.jar
16|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-jaxb_2.17.0.jar
17|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.utils_2.4.0.b10.jar
18|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet_2.17.0.jar
19|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client_2.17.0.jar
20|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar
21|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javassist_3.18.1.GA.jar
22|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
23|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.external.javax.inject_2.4.0.b10.jar
24|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher_4.3.0.201503290743.jar
25|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.mongodb.mongo-java-driver_2.13.0.RELEASE.jar
26|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.asm_5.0.1.v201405080102.jar
27|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/com.google.gson_2.3.1.jar
28|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
29|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
30|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
31|Active     |    1|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.200.v20131126-2331.jar
32|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.api_2.4.0.b10.jar
33|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar
34|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.16.v20140903.jar
35|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.v20140131-1639.jar
36|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.provider.security_2.1.0.201503290743.jar
37|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javax.el_2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
38|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javax.ws.rs-api_2.0.1.jar
39|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator_1.0.1.jar
40|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged.jersey-guava_2.17.0.jar
41|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging_3.1.3.GA.jar
42|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar
43|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.external.aopalliance-repackaged_2.4.0.b10.jar
44|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javax.servlet-api_3.0.1.jar
45|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar
46|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common_2.17.0.jar
47|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.hk2.locator_2.4.0.b10.jar
48|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/javax.annotation-api_1.2.0.jar
49|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.commons.configuration_1.10.0.jar
50|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar
51|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.6.v20150224-172222-092690e7bf.jar
52|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.commons.lang_2.6.0.jar
53|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.web.javax.el_2.2.4.jar
54|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar
55|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core_2.17.0.jar
56|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar
57|Active     |    4|initial@reference:file:plugins/org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server_2.17.0.jar
```

***Change in data model which causes the problem:***

from:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Role implements Serializable {

    public static final String COMMON = "common";
    public static final String REGISTRANT = "registrant";
    ...
```

to:

```
@XmlEnum(String.class)
public enum Role {

    @XmlEnumValue("common") COMMON ("common"),
    @XmlEnumValue("registrant") REGISTRANT ("registrant"),
    @XmlEnumValue("laborant") LABORANT ("laborant"),
    ...
```

Usage looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Principal, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    ...
```

and

```
@PUT @Path("/{name}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public Response register(@PathParam("name") String name, @Valid User user) {
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't looks like OSGi but more like ClassLoader problem. Can you provide more details about how to reproduce this?

Comment: @IaroslavSavytskyi getting my app to work in OSGi was a real pain (I admit, a lot of it was caused by Equinox and it's Eclipse tooling). There are 57 bundles in the container just to make a simple Jersey-based REST API + Mongodb. I don't think that it would make sense to try to reproduce it by you or anyone else. If you say it is probably Classloader problem then I'm going to switch back from enum to class and maybe from OSGi to classic web app. Thank you for your comment. I deluded myself that maybe it's some stupid problem with my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I belive it may be caused by a missing entry in the Import-Package manifest header in the bundle that uses JAXB. I had a similar stacktrace and when I added `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb` it worked.

Cf. the following snippet for the Maven Bundle Plugin:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It was Equinox, not Felix and Maven was not involved here. The source of problem was probably Equinox's caching mechanism.

Comment: OK, cool!

But please note that even if there was a caching problem involved the error indicates a class loading issue similar to what I experienced (cf the stacktrace). This I did resolve by adding the right package to the OSGI header `Import-Package` in my bundle's `MANIFEST.MF` file. If this header was present in your bundle's manifest clearly it was not the source of the error.

That I used the `maven-bundle-plugin` from Felix to do so is incidental to the answer; I might as well have manually edited the manifest before creating the JAR file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing import package in your OSGi manifest file. Only add this line to your manifest file, this is in the `MANIFEST.MF` from the bundle where the `Role` class is located:

```
DynamicImport-Package: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.*,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.*
```

And BTW, you don't need the annotation `@XmlEnum(String.class)` above the `Role` class, leave it as a simple POJO, it will work.

Comment: I can't test it anymore, because MOXy has been dropped from the project, but declaring import of internal packages looks wrong by design.

Comment: @SewerynNiemiec Remember that the `internal` package is only for the use of `maven-bundle-plugin`, it is not an OSGi specification and it tells the plugin only to not export that package and anything else inside it in the manifest, but in this case the MOXy library does export that package (so seems like they didn't use the `maven-bundle-plugin` after all). And as they have this package exported, it says you can import it. And your compiler is not adding this import automatically because you have no direct dependency to it, so you have to include it manually by adding this line. It works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ChristofferSoop answer.

If you work in an eclipse environment, you just need to add the MOXy bundle to your list of dependencies.